# Problems with view URL on drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I've a problem with my drupal view at path I uses `/persons`, this works fine.

http://example.org/persons/ shows the right view,

but when I type http://example.org/persons/asdasd it show's my view, too. But I only want to show the view under http://example.org/persons/

How can I avoid that problem or is there some setting I've missed? 
[image]

Comment: Could you please provide an image of the view configuration panel? Check your URL is "persons" instead of "persons/%", which would accept parameters

Comment: Hi its defenitly persons not persons/% I'll put a screenshot online

Comment: Check the list of URL alias and search for patterns including "person". Maybe it was once written but never deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

Edit the view and open **Advanced**, on the right top
[image: Edit the view and open **Advanced**, on the right top]

Add a contextual filter: **Global: Null**
[image: Add a contextual filter: **Global: Null**]

Tick 'Display all results', Click **More** at the bottom and tick **'Fail basic validation if any argument is given'**
[image: Tick 'Display all results', Click **More** at the bottom and tick **'Fail basic validation if any argument is given'**]

Now, if you put anything in front of the url, it will give you a 404 page